Send a Ctrl+C via a serial connection
I'm dealing with a Flipper Zero that's connected via Serial (over USB) to my laptop.
To write to a file, I have to end the transmission with Ctrl+C. But, neither ^C nor the ASCII End Of Text character seem to have the effect of actually ending the transmission.
What character would actually work in that case?

Do you see any confirmation on your laptop that the Flipper Zero understands your comms? If not, I would double check that your baud rate is correct. What happens if you close the port from the laptop end - that might trigger an end-of-transmission?

I know that it's receiving and understanding the commands, I can issue commands like turning the vibration motor on and off, and those work when piped in from a file. Closing the port (as would happen when my cat finishes) doesn't trigger that either - it stays in the terminal, and if I connect afterwards and press Ctrl+C, it writes it to the FS.

This doesn't answer my question, but may be useful for those that are dealing with something similar when developing a Flipper application:
ufbt launch

This command uploads the last compiled FAP to the flipper, and launches it. It won't be written to the FS, but it works if you're developing an application.
